# How to connect ibmmq 9.1 with any application i.e like (java, vb.net, python etc..)

Tags: ibm-mq

In order to connect any application with ibmmq 9.1, what are the steps we need to follow , how to connect ibmmq with any application.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that if you are new to IBM MQ that you start [here](https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/) and go through the tutorials.

Comment: In addition to the tutorials, you can find samples here - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns

Answer (score 0):

There are many samples shipped with product that you can refer to develop applications in Java and .NET. One simple sample written in Java JMS that receives message from a queue.

```
private void receiveWithContext(){
    JmsConnectionFactory cf = null;
    JMSContext msgContext = null;
    
    try {
        JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
        cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM");
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);
        msgContext = cf.createContext("youruserid","yourpassword",JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Queue jmsQ = msgContext.createQueue("Q1");
        JMSConsumer msgCons = msgContext.createConsumer(jmsQ);
        Message msg = msgCons.receiveNoWait();          
    }catch(JMSException jmsEx){
        System.out.println(jmsEx);
    }
}
```